# Asynchronous Results Assigned to a Sequential Array

Tags: node.js

I'm doing Exercise 9 of LearnYouNode. The goal of the exercise is to print the contents of the HTTP results in the order of the arguments given on the command line. Everything seems to be working correctly, but they are not staying in order. I realize that having the jobId inside the callback is wrong because it won't execute until it completes, but I'm still completely blocked on how to make it behave as intended. Just a FYI, I'm trying to do this without using Async or any other libraries for educational purposes. Also, any other tips based on my coding not related to my problem would be appreciated!

```
const http = require('http');

urls = process.argv.slice(2, process.argv.length);

function multiGetter (urlList, callback) {
    var results = new Array(urlList.length);
    var current = 0;
    var completed = 0;
    var hasErrors = false;


    function done(err) {
        if(err) {
            hasErrors = true;
            return callback(err);
        }
        if(++completed === urlList.length && !hasErrors) {
            callback(null, results);
        }
    }

    urls.forEach( (url) => {
        http.get(url, (res) => {
            let jobId = current;
            current++;
            results[jobId] = '';
            res.setEncoding('utf8')
               .on('error', (e) => { console.error(e.message); })
               .on('data', (data) => { results[jobId] += data; })
               .on('end', () => { done(null); });
        }).on('error', console.error);
    });
}

multiGetter(urls, (err, contents) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error;
    }
    contents.forEach(result => {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this could be the following:

- change the `results` variable into an object instead of an array: `var results = {};`
- assign to `jobId` the value of `url` instead of `current` (you can get rid of the `current` variable)

Finally, in your callback at the bottom, change the iteration to:

```
urls.forEach(url => {
    console.log(contents[url]);
});
```